# How to exclude a whole word including an escaped character from a search?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find a way to match a single character except if it's inside a specific word.

The problem is I'm trying to find all the '/', but not the ones inside 'TCP/IP'. I found that a Negative Lookahead would do the job, but the problem is to exclude the whole 'TCP/IP' word.
When I escape the '/', it makes the negative lookahead wrong.

The tested Regex is:

```
(?!TCP\/IP)\/
```

The data to test:

```
PHP/JAVA/TCP/IP/PYTHON/JAVASCRIPT
```

It should match every '/', except the one inside 'TCP/IP'

However, when I'm testing the regex with regex101.com, my negative lookahead part goes numb as I add the /:

```
Negative Lookahead (?!TCP\/IP)
Assert that the Regex below does not match
TCP matches the characters TCP literally (case insensitive)
\/ matches the character / literally (case insensitive)
IP matches the characters IP literally (case insensitive)
```

It seems like it's not considered as a single word anymore.

I think it can be fixed easily, but I'm out of solution at the moment.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us what your expected output is here?

Comment: Yes, of course:
PHP**/**JAVA**/**TCP/IP**/**PYTHON**/**JAVASCRIPT

I'm having trouble formating it. But basically the / that are between ** **

Comment: @Barzou The reason that your formatting doesn't work is due to the fact that it only works if there is a non-word character before or after the text. This: \*\*text\*\* becomes: **text**. Due to the fact that there is no letters before or after the asterisks. What you want can only be achieved using <strong></strong> tags, but SO doesn't allow HTML tags in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of matching the slashes to split you could also use the "reverse" regex to find all the matches.

```js
const string = "PHP/JAVA/TCP/IP/PYTHON/JAVASCRIPT";
const regex = /(TCP\/IP)(?=\/|$)|[^/]+/g;
//             ^       ^
// The group is unnecessary here, but is required in my second example.

console.log(string.match(regex));
```

If you've more exceptions you can make this dynamic by doing the following:

```js
const string = "PHP/JAVA/TCP/IP/PYTHON/JAVASCRIPT/AB/CDE/FOO/UDP/TCP/AB/CD";
const exceptions = ["TCP/IP", "AB/CD", "AB/CDE", "UDP/TCP"];

// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Escaping
function escapeRegExp(string) {
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
}

let pattern = exceptions.map(escapeRegExp).join('|');
    pattern = `(${pattern})(?=/|$)|[^/]+`;
const regex = new RegExp(pattern, "g");

console.log(string.match(regex));
```

Let me give you a short rundown of what this does.

1. First escape all regex special characters inside the `exceptions` array.
2. Join them together with the `|` character (regex OR).
3. Now for the regex itself. Match one of the exceptions. The match must be followed by either an `/` character or the end of the string (`$`). If none of the the exceptions match, check if the character is a non-`/`. If this is the case match as many non-`/` as possible.

**Note:** If you for some reason have the exceptions `A/B` and `A/B/C`, you should rearrange the array so that `A/B/C` comes before `A/B`. If this is not done you get the matches `["A/B", "C"]` for the string `"A/B/C"` due to the fact that the `A/B` is indeed followed by a forward slash. Sorting the array based on string length (largest first) resolves this.

Comment: If you want case insensitive matching add the `i` flag to the examples above.

Comment: I implemented something thanks to your solution. Thanks. :) Testing right now. ;)

Answer (score 1):

No `The "negative lookbehind" feature may not be supported in all browsers.` warning.

```js
const string = 'PHP/JAVA/TCP/IP/PYTHON/JAVASCRIPT/ABC/ABDEFIP';
const regex = /\/(?![^TCP]*IP)/g;
const output = string.replace(regex, ' ');

console.log(output);
```

Comment: `[^TCP]*` doesn't do what you think it does. Try adding `/ABC/ABDEFIP` to the end of the string.

Comment: fyi - The current regex says. Match a `/` if not followed by any amount of non-`[TCP]` characters. Followed by `IP`. My example has a `/`. Followed by the characters `ABDEF`, which are all non-`[TCP]` characters. Followed by `IP`.

Comment: Got that, thanks for the info. Everyone else who need this circumstance, should look at @3limin4t0r [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56481795/2806103) below.

Answer (score 1):

As negative  lookbehinds are not fully supported, you might match what you do not want and capture what you do want in a capturing group.

Your values are in the first capturing group `$1`

```
\bTCP\/IP\b|(\/)
```

That will match:

- `\bTCP\/IP\b` Match TCP/IP between word boundaries
- `|`
- `(!\/)` capture a forward slash in group 1

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jq9eiD/1)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use Regexr to build a Regex that matched what I believe you're asking - every `/` that does not exist within `TCP/IP`.

I had to split your lookaround into a negative lookbehind for TCP (`(?<!TCP)`) then the `/` (`\/`) then a negative lookahead for IP (`(?!IP)`)

The resulting Regex is `(?<!TCP)\/(?!IP)`

See: https://regexr.com/4fccb

Comment: This indeed matches my request, thanks.
But what if I want to exclude '/' from more words? (which is the final goal)
With a single lookahead, it's easy with the OR operator ( | ), but in this case, I don't see how to do it. :(

Comment: You can use `|` within the lookarounds. For example, add `/TACO/SAUCE/OTHER/STUFF` to your search string, then try this Regex: `(?<!TCP|TACO)\/(?!IP|SAUCE)`

This might pretty unwieldy when dealing with large amounts of data that contain the same character they're delimited with. Unless you can change the source data to use a different delimiter, this is the best option I can think of. But I can't imagine you'd ask such a request if it was as easy as changing the / to another character :)

Comment: Yes, if I was able to control the data source, it would be muuchhhh simpler.
Thanks for the solution, I will implement it as it seems to solve my problem. :)
Have a good day.

Comment: Keep in mind that look behinds are [not yet supported in all major browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Browser_compatibility) (you tagged the question with JavaScript). Furthermore you should also note that `(?<!TCP|TACO)\/(?!IP|SAUCE)` also doesn't match the slash in `TCP/SAUCE` or `TACO/IP`, thus not only `TCP/IP` and `TACO/SAUCE`.

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out a way to do this with pure regex, but an alternative to regex would be to just split on `/`, and then iterate the resulting array once to handle the edge case of a `TCP/IP` entry:

```js
var input = "PHP/JAVA/TCP/IP/PYTHON/JAVASCRIPT"
var parts = input.split("/")
var keep = [];
var flag = false;
for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    if (parts[i] == "TCP") {
        flag = true;
        keep.push(parts[i]);
        continue;
    }
    else if (parts[i] == "IP" && flag) {
        keep.pop();
        keep.push("TCP/IP");
    }
    else {
        keep.push(parts[i]);
    }
    flag = false;
}

console.log(keep);
```